Rules about "original ATK" text in cards - a scenario
I'm playing Yu-Gi-Oh!1 and I have a doubt about the following scenario:

Turn 3 - my turn - and in my field I have the following cards:


Destiny HERO - Defender (face-up in defense position).
D2 Shield (ready for be activated).
Cyber Dragon (face-up in attack position).


In my hand I have:


Megamorph
Maju Garzett
Shield & Sword


My play:


Activate "D2 Shield" on "Destiny HERO - Defender" = DEF: 5400
Activate "Shield & Sword" -> the original ATK of "Destiny HERO - Defender" now is: ATK: 5400
Fusion summon "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" (using my Cyber Dragon and 2 face-up machine monsters from my opponent) = original ATK: 3200 (my opponent has the continuous spell "Machine Assembly Line" face-up, with 1 counter on it).
Tribute summon "Maju Garzett" = ATK: 100?, how so?

Issue: Since the original ATK of the tributed monsters where modified and set (the case for "Destiny HERO - Defender") and "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" was summoned as required, "Maju Garzett" should have an ATK of 8600.
My question(s) are:

How (despite the fact), the original ATK of the tributed monsters where set using the card(s) mentioned above (and with their effect - see "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon"), "Maju Garzett" didn't get the expected ATK?
In the case I'm wrong, can you please point me about the rules that explains how the original ATK works in Yu-Gi-Oh!?
My intention is to use cards that modified the original ATK of monsters that will be tributted for either "Maju Garzett" and&or "Great Maju Garzett".


1 Currently playing Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5 (and I made the described play on this game), but I'm looking for answers that applies to this version of the game as well for Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel, Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links and the TCG.

I always thought, original ATK and original DEF refer to the ATK and DEF values of a Monster Card before any monster, Spell, or Trap Cards alter the value. They are the ATK and DEF values listed on the card.

The ruling have changed through the years, so some of the stats change calculations may be different between Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5 and the more modern Yu-Gi-Oh! (including the TCG). So, I will be using my knowledge of the current ruling (I have a link to judge resources from a few years ago which should still be up to date)
Let's start by explaining the difference between original and current ATK/DEF:

Original ATK/DEF: The ATK/DEF written on the monster card, which can be affected by certain effects like "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon"'s own effect.
Current ATK/DEF: Any change to the ATK/DEF, like using an equip spell card.

Now, let's break down your play:

Activate "D2 Shield" on "Destiny HERO - Defender" = DEF: 5400

D2 Shield doesn't change the original DEF of the monster, it only sets the current DEF to double the original DEF. "Destiny HERO - Defender" still has an original DEF of 2600 but a current DEF of 5400.

Activate "Shield & Sword" -> the original ATK of "Destiny HERO - Defender" now is: ATK: 5400

"Shield & Sword" swaps the original ATK and DEF, the original DEF of "Destiny HERO - Defender" was 2600, so its new original ATK is 2600.
Note: I am unsure if the effect of D2 Shield would reapply on the new original DEF of 100 or not, but it doesn't concern us in this scenario.

Fusion summon "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" (using my Cyber Dragon and 2 face-up machine monsters from my opponent) = original ATK: 3200 (my opponent has the continuous spell "Machine Assembly Line" face-up, with 1 counter on it).

The original ATK of "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" would be 3000 with 3 tributes. Its current attack is 3200 thanks to the effect of "Machine Assembly Line".

Tribute summon "Maju Garzett" = ATK: 100?, how so?

At this point, you are tributing "Destiny HERO - Defender" with an original ATK of 2600 (current ATK = 2600) and "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" with an original ATK of 3000 (current ATK = 3200). Now, the effect of "Maju Garzett" applies:

The ATK of this card becomes equal to the combined original ATK of the 2 monsters you Tributed for the Tribute Summon of this card.

It takes the original ATK of the tributed monsters, so it should have an ATK of 2600 + 3000 = 5600.
Why does it end up wih an ATK of 100? Because when you're tributing monsters, they are sent to the GY. At this point, all the effects applied to these monsters are cancelled, including the changes to original and current stats. "Maju Garzett" effectively takes the original ATK of the 2 monsters in the GY, respectively 100 and 0.

Thank you. The last paragraph pretty much explain the case. I posted this question as well here as well and the response matches. This case looks weird to me, though, the card text says original ATK, so, my scenario should be correct, but, oh, well, Yu-Gi-Oh!, right?
